# differential equation led to $\ln(0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider 
$$-bv-\mu mg+F=m\frac{dv}{dt},$$

where $b,μ,m,g,F$ are constants.

I'm not sure how to solve it,
I tried $$\int_0^v-bv/dv=\int_0^t(m+\mu mg-F)/dt,$$

which led to $\ln(0)-\ln(bv).$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show your steps and how you are getting that?

Comment: $$\int_0^v-dv/bv=\int_0^t(dt/(m+\mu mg -F)$$
$$\ln(|b*0|)-ln(|bv|)=...$$

Comment: @MikeL the integration you do above is over different variables on left vs. right sides. This is ok, but you must be fair and integrate over appropriate bounds. Let $v_o$ be the velocity at time zero then $\int_{v_o}^v( ...) = \int^t_0 (...)$. There may be other errors, I just wanted to point you to this one since it is important to remedy for future work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint 1:**

Instead, write this as:

$$\tag 1 \dfrac{dv}{dt} = \dfrac{F -\mu m g -b v}{m}$$

**Hint 2:**

Can you see you how to approach solving this?

How about writing (since these are mostly constants) as:

$$\tag 2 \left(\dfrac{m~dv}{F -\mu m g -b v}\right) = 1 dt$$

Now, can you integrate both sides to solve for $v(t)$, which will have an unknown constant given you do not have initial conditions?

Comment: Thanks for that, but how do you know which side the constants go to?

Comment: You need to seperate things to get the equation in a form that you can solve. This need not be unique. For example, we could easily move $m$ to the RHS as $dt/m$ and things will still work out. So, the only rule is that all operations have to be legal while putting the DEQ in a form you can work with. Try this with "m" on each side and prove to yourself you get the same result, perhaps different by a constant. Regards

Comment: Nice work here, Amzoti (+1).

Comment: @BabakS.: Hello my friend! Hope all is well and your are having a great day! Regards

Comment: @BabakS.: This particular OP posted a cogent question, posted what he tried and was downvoted. I am at a loss as to why. I think people are harsh, particularly to the very new users! It is discouraging and I do not believe really speaks to what we want - for these posters to grow and learn to be great problem solvers! Regards